QRawFont path for glyph size is wrong
Using Windows 10, with Qt 6.8, I'm trying to make an SVG Reader within my application, to change it to GCode. However, I have a problem with text size.
Here is a small example showing my problem :
#include <QApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <QRawFont>
#include <QPainterPath>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QFont font("Arial");
    font.setPointSizeF(12);
    QRawFont rawFont = QRawFont::fromFont(font);
    auto glyphs = rawFont.glyphIndexesForString("a");
    for (auto glyph : glyphs) {
        QPainterPath letterPath = rawFont.pathForGlyph(glyph);
        std::cout << "Letter path size: X: " << letterPath.boundingRect().width()
                  << " Y: " << letterPath.boundingRect().height() << std::endl;
    }
    return app.exec();
}

This is the output of this code :
Letter path size: X: 7.64062 Y: 8.67188

But in InkScape, when I write the letter 'a', change it to a path, and measure it, the values are not the same :
x: 5.731 y: 6.504

There's a 0.75 ratio between InkScape size and the size of the QPainterPath generated.
Note: text scale on Windows is set to 100%.

72dpi/96dpi = 0.75
